# Prevent column break in multicolumn index

Tags: page-breaking, indexing

I am using `imakeidx` to generate a multicolumn index with `makeindex`.

Here is an excerpt from my `.ind`:

```
  \item \BRbooktitlestyle {\BRepistlenumberstyle {1}Jean}                       
    \subitem \BRchapterstyle {2}\BRchvsep \BRversestyle {2} \dotfill            
                \textrm{18}                                                     
    \subitem \BRchapterstyle {4}\BRchvsep \BRversestyle {9}\BRvrsep \BRversestyle {10} \dotfill
                \textrm{18}
```

where `\BRfoo` are `bibleref` formatting macros. Unfortunately, the `\item` is at the bottom of a left column, so the `\subitems` get pushed to the right column:

[image: column break in index]

Is there an equivalent to `\nobreak` which could be used here to prevent this behaviour, and how?

Comment: Try `\makeatletter\g@addto@macro\@idxitem\nobreak\makeatother`in your preamble.

Comment: This forces everything on one column and one page...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want that a column break is preferred before each `\item` command; the usual definition of `\item` in an index is `\par\hangindent 40\p@`; so something like

```
\indexsetup{othercode={\let\item\breakitem}}
```

may do what needed, after saying in the preamble

```
\makeatletter
\def\breakitem{\par\goodbreak\hangindent 40\p@}
\makeatother
```

Another trick could be to add

```
\vadjust{\nobreak}
```

to the definition of `\BRbooktitlestyle`

Comment: This is perfect! I used the second trick since I'm already redefining the style.

Comment: That is really helpful! Unfortunately, I gave a (private) book into print two days ago without this (I had only `\nobreak`), but the next edition will benefit from your trick. Adding `\vadjust{\nobreak}` works perfectly.