# How to prevent column break in multicols environment

Tags: page-breaking, multicol

I am typesetting a simple songbook and would like some songs to be displayed in two columns (I use the `multicol` package). However, I would like to prevent inserting a columnbreak within a stanza. It would be great to have something like a `samecol` environment.

I tried to apply hints from [Prevent column break in multicolumn index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21612/prevent-column-break-in-multicolumn-index), but it didn't yield the expected result.

I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Couldn't `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}...\end{minipage}` serve as a `samecol` environment?

Comment: doesn't \begin{samepage}..\end{somepage} work?

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions. `minipage` works, of course with its usual drawbacks. `samepage` doesn't work.

Comment: I want this question to be answered correctly. I have a MWE. What is the best way for me to share my MWE? Should I start a new question?

Comment: @ahorn: Post it to [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and then add the link to this post. I assume your setup is similar to the question?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/T6K6pNwG
@Werner, yes, I have exactly the same question.

Comment: I want to find a solution that isn't time-consuming to type in, because there are hundreds of songs in my song book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer accidentally, while looking for something else. In order to prevent column break within a stanza I mark line ends with `\\*` instead of `\\`.
Example:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{verse}       
     I heard, I heard, the old man say,\\*
     John Kanaka-naka tu-lai-ay!\\*
     Today, today is a holiday,\\*
     John Kanaka-naka tu-lai-ay!

     Tu-lai-ay, Oh! Tu-lai-ay!\\*
     John Kanaka-naka tu-lai-ay!
  \end{verse} 
 \end{multicols}
```

I realize this does not solve the general problem of column break prevention,
but perfectly fits my needs.

Comment: Maybe you would like to accept your own answer! Relevant discussions: [I accepted my answer to own question: Own answers should be possible to be accepted after some(?) votes of commited tex.se users](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2639/8272) and [Accept Your Own Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).

Comment: didn't work for me, at least for a verbatim block :(

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you take a look at the [needspace](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/needspace) package and its macro `\Needspace{}`. This macro should be invoked with the number of lines that need to be kept together, expressed in multiples of `\baselineskip`. Thus, `\Needspace{5\baselineskip}` will keep the next five lines together by forcing a column break, if necessary, before the start of the stanza. Note that it should only be used between paragraphs (stanzas).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, it doesn't work. Maybe due to the fact that inside `multicol` environment I put the`verse` environment.

Comment: @mac-p - thanks for this feedback. Please consider editing your question to include a more specific description; providing a full MWE (minimum working example) that reproduces the problem in question would be especially helpful. Hopefully, having this additional information will help me and/or others figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that works for me, although the factor that `\linewidth` needs to be multiplied by may need to be adjusted in different situations:

Put

```
\newenvironment{stanza}
   {\begin{minipage}{1.1\linewidth} \begin{verse}}
   {\end{verse} \end{minipage}}
```

in the preamble, and use the `stanza` environment for the stanzas that are troublesome.

Comment: Well, it's the first time I'm not going to award a bounty.