# Index: How to move letter group heading from the bottom of one column to the next column?

Tags: indexing, xindy

I am using `xindy` for my index but I get this here:

[image: heading on bottom of column]

Does anyone know why a single letter (group heading) remains on the bottom of a column? How to force it into the next column?

It will be hard to create a MWE since the only command used is: `\printindex`... However here is some of the contents of the `*.ind` file:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{A}
  \item \vn ạ, 114
  \item \vn ai, 19, 42
    \subitem ai chẳng, 39
    \subitem ai cũng, 38

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{Â}
  \item \vn âm, 33
```

...

```
  \item \vn ơi, 76

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{P}
  \item \vn phải, 2, 45, 84, 120
    \subitem phải không, 3
  \item \vn phảy, 33
  \item \vn phần, 32

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{Q}
```

...

```
  \item \vn xong, 43

\end{theindex}
```

Comment: possibly relevant: http://sourceforge.net/p/xindy/bugs/34/

Comment: open your .ind file and tell us if you find something like \begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  } with this code I can't create a MWE reproducing your problem

Comment: @FrancescoEndrici I added the content of the `*.ind` file to the question. Is there some way to not only avoid a page break (as `\nopagebreak` does) but also a column break?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21612/prevent-column-break-in-multicolumn-index does it work for you? You could write a style file adding a goodbreak before \lettergroup