# Komascript ToC: Prevent column break between sections in multicolumn ToC

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, multicol

When using a multicolumn table of contents, the column breaks commonly occur between subsections which is ugly as hell.

Solution from esdd which allows several permutations was this:

```
%Two column ToC: comment lines to get combination of v.kern and column break you want
\usepackage{multicol}
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2} }  %this keeps heading "Contents" out of two column block
%\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}} %keep cols equal i.e. vertical kern
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\null\end{multicols}} %2nd column is shorter, no v.kern
\RedeclareSectionCommand[toconstartsamelevel={}]{subsection} %Only break Column at Section,not sub-section.
```

See: [Prevent column break in multicolumn index](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21612/prevent-column-break-in-multicolumn-index) , except I am trying to do it for Table of Contents...

[image]

I am trying to put the ToC at the bottom of the 1st page thus )...

```
\begin{table}[!b]
\rule[0.5ex]{1\columnwidth}{0.5pt}
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2}} %could be in preamble...
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}
\tableofcontents{}
\end{table}
```

Is there a direct way to make the toc float at bottom of page (i.e. not using table)?

Note: \BeforeStartingTOC makes the heading "Contents"  above the two columns section, so it looks better that example above.

MWE

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%Two column ToC: comment lines to get combination of v.kern and column break you want
\usepackage{multicol}

\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2} }  %this keeps heading "Contents" out of two column block
%\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}} %keep cols equal  vertical kerns
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\null\end{multicols}} %2nd column is shorter, no v.kern
\RedeclareSectionCommand[toconstartsamelevel={}]{subsection} %Only break Column at Section,not sub-section.


\makeatother

 \usepackage{babel}
 \begin{document}

 \title{A Koma Article}

 \maketitle
 \tableofcontents{}

 \section{First}
 \subsection{F1}
 \subsection{F2}
 \section{Second}
 \subsection{S1}
 \subsection{S2}
 \subsection{S3}
 \subsection{S4}
 \section{Third}
 \section{Fourth}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Why a `table` float? Also, why also setting the chapter title in two-column mode? Also, why not posting a minimal working example? It is very hard to constuct something that matches your output, and we still cannot be sure it matches your code and a solution will work for you. In case it does not work, because your code is different, one of use would have wasted his/her time.

Comment: How else to float the toc to the bottom of the page? Is there a neater way (like a koma option for position)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your MWE is

[image]

`scrartcl` avoids a break between a section entry and its first subsection entry.

I am not sure if you really want no break between subsection entries. The result could be really ugly:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    toconstartsamelevel={}
]{subsection}
```

[image]

Or

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    toconstartsamelevel={},
    tocbeforeskip=0pt
]{subsection}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}[2016/05/10]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%Two column ToC
\usepackage{multicol}
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2} }
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\end{multicols}}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    toconstartsamelevel={},
    tocbeforeskip=0pt
]{subsection}

 \usepackage{babel}
 \begin{document}
 \title{A Koma Article}
 \maketitle
 \tableofcontents
 \section{First}
 \subsection{F1}
 \subsection{F2}
 \section{Second}
 \subsection{S1}
 \subsection{S2}
 \subsection{S3}
 \subsection{S4}
 \section{Third}
 \section{Fourth}
 \end{document}
```

---

Or

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}[2016/05/10]
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%Two column ToC
\usepackage{multicol}
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\begin{multicols}{2} }
\AfterStartingTOC[toc]{\null\end{multicols}}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    toconstartsamelevel={},
]{subsection}

 \usepackage{babel}
 \begin{document}
 \title{A Koma Article}
 \maketitle
 \tableofcontents
 \section{First}
 \subsection{F1}
 \subsection{F2}
 \section{Second}
 \subsection{S1}
 \subsection{S2}
 \subsection{S3}
 \subsection{S4}
 \section{Third}
 \section{Fourth}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like what I want, but I get error - Package scrbase Error: unknown option ` toconstartsamelevel={} '.      Member `.dsc' of family `KOMAarg'
cannot handle option `toconstartsamelevel'.
So it cannot be set.
                (Komascript is V3.15, jan2015)

Comment: Option `toconstartsamelevel` needs at least KOMA version 3.20. Current version is 3.21

Comment: Thanks it works great[my bad, I assumed miktex packagemanager showed current versions]. Is there any option to force position to bottom of page, or better way that using a table float?      BTW It would be great if you commented the key lines. for example I have no idea `why /null/end` is doing what it does. I have updated my MWE.